# Легально ли операторы new и delete, объявленные в одном классе, применять для другого класса?

Tags: c++, классы, delete, new

Допустим, я объявил некоторый класс-контейнер, содержащий перегруженные операторы `new()` и `delete()`:

```
class MyNewContainer
{
public:
    INLINE void* operator new(size_t uMemSize)                    {...}
    INLINE void* operator new[](size_t uMemSize)                  {...}
    INLINE void operator delete(void* pMem)                       {...}
    INLINE void operator delete(void* pMem, size_t uMemSize)      {...}
    INLINE void operator delete[](void* pMem)                     {...}
    INLINE void operator delete[](void* pMem, size_t uMemSize)    {...}
};
```

И допустим, я объявил следующий шаблон класса (пусть будет элемент односвязного списка):

```
template <typename TData, class TNewContainer>
class CNode
{
    CNode*  m_pNextNode;
    TData   m_data;

public:
    template <typename... TArgs> INLINE CNode(TArgs... args): m_pNextNode(NULL), m_data(args...) {}
    INLINE CNode(CNode& rSrcNode): m_data(rSrcNode.m_data) {}
    INLINE CNode& operator=(CNode& rSrcNode) = delete;

    INLINE void* operator new(size_t uMemSize)               {return TNewContainer::operator new(uMemSize);}
    INLINE void operator delete(void* pMem)                  {TNewContainer::operator delete(pMem);}
    INLINE void operator delete(void* pMem, size_t uMemSize) {TNewContainer::operator delete(pMem,uMemSize);}
    ......
};
```

И, соответственно, пример использования выше приведенных классов:

```
auto pNode = new CNode<int,MyNewContainer>();
```

Вопрос: насколько в C++ легален такой подход к кастомизации операций создания/удаления объектов?

На практике этот приём показал прекрасные результаты, всё компилируется и работает так, как я и задумал. Однако зная о наличии огромного фолианта всевозможных неочевидных запретов и правил в языке C++, нарушение которых в большинстве случаев не приводит к потере работоспособности кода, но тем не менее формально считается UB, я всё же хочу спросить у профессионалов: действительно ли не запрещается применять операторы `new()` и `delete()`, объявленные в одном классе, для создания/удаления объектов совсем другого класса?

Comment: Как ответ, давать боюсь, но поскольку операторы просто выделяют кусок памяти запрошенного размера и не более того — то вроде бы вполне легально...

Comment: @Harry если так, то это радует. Просто я заметил закономерность: как только придумываю какую-нибудь фичу, то часто потом оказывается, что эта фича запрещена. У меня уже выработалась фобия, боюсь мыслить нестандартно. А то вдруг ub. "Если твой код работает, то это не значит, что он верен" - пожалуй, самый удручающий вывод, который напрашивается после определённого опыта программирования на C++...

Comment: Трудно с вами не согласиться, что это самая неприятная вещь в программировании на С++ :) Лично меня больше всего злят strict aliasing, правила которых простым языком так ничто и не смог мне объяснить, а равно все эти выравнивания...

Comment: По крайней мере в спецификации я ничего запрещающего не нашел

Comment: @Mister_Jesus я тоже. Как и ничего разрешающего. Но то, что явно не запрещено, считаем что разрешено, не так ли?)) Я пока решил следовать этому принципу. Уж больно красивое решение, чтобы от него отказываться...